# Ktor sse client disconnect

Tags: kotlin, server-sent-events, ktor

Ktor has support for server side events in the sense that I can use the text/server-event content type. It works pretty well, but on client disconnect e.g. Browser window close/manual close call, it will still continue sending events, as it doesn't detect the disconnect until the next event, where it will throw an exception. Is there any way to get a event for client disconnect in a ktor request so that we can stop sending server side events and also cleanup resources?

Answer (score 1):

Websocket Ktor implementation has `pinger` extension which do the same for websockets. So I think it's totally valid has the same for SSE. I thought that it will be better to file a feature request here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KTOR.

As we use SSE in Ktor in production we implemented pinging clients as a background coroutine. It just sends empty event each 30 seconds and if it's fail connection will be closed. It prevents connections leaks in case when user is disconnected but server still holds connection.